# spaCy Classifier: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_array'

Tags: python, nlp, classification, spacy

I'm trying to code a minimal text classifier with spaCy. I wrote the following snippet of code to train just the text categorizer (without training the whole NLP pipeline):

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import TextCategorizer
nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc1 = u'This is my first document in the dataset.'
doc2 = u'This is my second document in the dataset.'

gold1 = u'Category1'
gold2 = u'Category2'

textcat = TextCategorizer(nlp.vocab)
textcat.add_label('Category1')
textcat.add_label('Category2')
losses = {}
optimizer = textcat.begin_training()
textcat.update([doc1, doc2], [gold1, gold2], losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
```

But when I run it, it returns an error. Here is the traceback it gives me when I start it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Reuben\Desktop\Classification\Classification\Training.py", line
 16, in <module>
    textcat.update([doc1, doc2], [gold1, gold2], losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 838, in spacy.pipeline.TextCategorizer.update
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py", line 61, in
begin_update
    X, inc_layer_grad = layer.begin_update(X, drop=drop)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py", line 176, in
 begin_update
    values = [fwd(X, *a, **k) for fwd in forward]
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py", line 258, in
 wrap
    output = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py", line 61, in
begin_update
    X, inc_layer_grad = layer.begin_update(X, drop=drop)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\_ml.py", line 95, in
_preprocess_doc
    keys = [doc.to_array(LOWER) for doc in docs]
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_array'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the traceback as text, instead of a blurry screenshot?

Comment: Good idea. I'll edit the post right now.

Comment: OK, obviously the problem is that at least one of the four strings (`unicode` objects) you're passing in that `textcat.update` call is supposed to be some other type of object. I don't know what kind, except that it needs to have a `to_array` method (which none of Python's builtin types have—nor do numpy/scipy/pandas or other similar things). I'm guessing it's some type from spacy itself.

Comment: Also, I notice from the first example on [the spacy homepage](https://spacy.io/) that they're doing `doc1 = nlp(u"my fries were super gross")`, while you're doing `doc1 = u'This is my first document in the dataset.'`. So, is it possible that you just need to call `nlp` on some or all those strings?

Comment: Gotcha. That sounds like an excellent guess, so I'll try that right now.

Comment: That gives me a  [similar error](https://pastebin.com/raw/9LyX696j).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `textcat` expects gold values which where made with `GoldParse`, not plaintext values. The working version looks like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import TextCategorizer
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc1 = nlp(u'This is my first document in the dataset.')
doc2 = nlp(u'This is my second document in the dataset.')

gold1 = GoldParse(doc=doc1, cats={'Category1': 1, 'Category2': 0})
gold2 = GoldParse(doc=doc2, cats={'Category1': 0, 'Category2': 1})

textcat = TextCategorizer(nlp.vocab)
textcat.add_label('Category1')
textcat.add_label('Category2')
losses = {}
optimizer = textcat.begin_training()
textcat.update([doc1, doc2], [gold1, gold2], losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
```

Thanks to @abarnert in the comments for helping me debug this.

Comment: Well, I never would have guessed that without reading the docs for that function (or an example that uses the `gold` submodule). Glad you found it. (But in the future, going right to the documentation—or the source, if there isn’t any—for the function that’s complaining is often the fastest way to find out what it expects.)